# when i add grouping function for creating a new column in DF, it's not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Group by result

empdf.groupby('deptno')['sal'].max()
deptno
10    5000.0
20    3000.0
30    2850.0

I joined this result to my DF empdf, but the result is not coming. Below is query and result.

empdf.assign(maxsal_dept = empdf.groupby('deptno')['sal'].max())

empno

ename

job

mgr

hiredate

sal

comm

deptno

totalsal

rnk

dnsrnk

maxsal_dept

0
7839 KING PRESIDENT NaN 1981-11-17 00:00:00 5000.0 50.0 10 5050.0 1 1 NaN

1
7698 BLAKE MANAGER 7839.0 1981-05-01 00:00:00 2850.0 285.0 30 3135.0 5 4 NaN

2
7782 CLARK MANAGER 7839.0 1981-06-09 00:00:00 2450.0 24.5 10 2474.5 6 5 NaN

3
7566 JONES MANAGER 7839.0 1981-04-02 00:00:00 2975.0 NaN 20 2975.0 4 3 NaN

4
7788 SCOTT ANALYST 7566.0 1987-04-19 00:00:00 3000.0 NaN 20 3000.0 2 2 NaN

5
7902 FORD ANALYST 7566.0 1981-12-03 00:00:00 3000.0 NaN 20 3000.0 3 2 NaN

6
7369 SMITH CLERK 7902.0 1980-12-17 00:00:00 800.0 NaN 20 800.0 14 12 NaN

[By grouping result is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrwKi.png)

[i want to add this group to DF for creating new column, but it's not giving right result. Highlited column in yellow color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aixe5.png)

Comment: post editable text instead of images. it would be easy for you to help.

Comment: i have posted data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `transform`

Try the below snippet

`empdf['maxsal_deptl']= empdf.groupby('deptno')['sal'].transform('max')`

Comment: I am actually transitioning to data science from my current platform DB developer. Thanks for your support.

Comment: All the best. Have a nice day.